# How to prevent React / React Native from automatically attaching a stacktrace to my console warnings in the React Native Debugger

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging, react-native-debugger

I like to use the console to debug my React-Native (0.63.4) application.
For some time now, React seems to automatically add a stack trace to my `console.warn` and `console.error` logs.
For example, the logs look like this in the Chrome debugger:

[image: screenshot of stacktrace added from react]

As you can see in the screenshot, the log message is actually collapsed (see small arrow in the upper left). So I assume that the stacktrace is added via some function in React in addition to the "normal" stacktrace. When I expand the message, the "normal" stacktrace of the Chrome debugger appears below, e.g.

[image: screenshot of chrome stacktrace]:

I'm sure this feature might be quite helpful, but the logs become completely illegible and confusing if they contain a few warnings. Therefore My question, does anyone know how to disable this feature?

Answer (score -3):

Actually, **The Debuggers are mainly used to debug the app or trace the issue** if we are facing anything in code.

So If there is an issue then we can get the proper stack of the issue to know from where the exact mistake is with which we can solve the problems in our code.

For this reason, we can accept that there will be no way to manage it manually.

Also, there is no manual documentation to manage the logs from React Native.

Comment: I am fully aware that stacktraces are helpful when debugging, but I was not asking why printing the stacktrace is useful, I was explicitly asking how to disable this feature as it might also be an obstacle in some situations.

Comment: @ChristophGöttert, Great to hear from you, also I have mentioned that there is no manuals for managing the logs, I understand the point you are conveying as sometimes I also feel that there should be something with which we can disable the logs.